# How do I plot a timeseries histogram using Elastic SQL in Kibana with Canvas?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

We have our monitoring data in Elasticsearch, visualized via Kibana, and I'm trying to put together some charts using the Canvas feature in Kibana. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the time series histogram to work.

Per the documentation, I'm trying to use this query to pull the data out for the plot:

```
SELECT HISTOGRAM("@timestamp", INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as t, count(*) as c FROM "nginx*"
```

And I get the error, when I try to use the "Preview" button:

```
[essql] > Unexpected error from Elasticsearch: [verification_exception] Found 1 problem(s) line 1:8: [HISTOGRAM("@timestamp", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)] needs to be part of the grouping
```

Someone in our office suggested that I add `GROUP BY t`, but that didn't do anything, and indeed returned the same error. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some other better way to get data out so I can set up a time series plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the histogram expression under `GROUP BY` will solve this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM "nginx*" GROUP BY HISTOGRAM("@timestamp", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: And what do we input under x-axis? y-axis should be the count c, but the visualization on the canvas doesn't do anything from this query